# Python Pandas Multiprocessing Apply

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I am wondering if there is a way to do a pandas dataframe apply function in parallel. I have looked around and haven't found anything. At least in theory I think it should be fairly simple to implement but haven't seen anything. This is practically the textbook definition of parallel after all.. Has anyone else tried this or know of a way? If no one has any ideas I think I might just try writing it myself.

The code I am working with is below. Sorry for the lack of import statements. They are mixed in with a lot of other things.

```
def apply_extract_entities(row):
     names=[]
     counter=0
     print row
     for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(open(row['file_name'], "r+b").read()):
         for chunk in nltk.ne_chunk(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sent))):
             if hasattr(chunk, 'node'):
                 names+= [chunk.node, ' '.join(c[0] for c in chunk.leaves())]
                 counter+=1
                 print counter
     return names

data9_2['proper_nouns']=data9_2.apply(apply_extract_entities, axis=1)
```

EDIT:

So here is what I tried. I tried running it with just the first five element of my iterable and it is taking longer than it would if I ran it serially so I assume it is not working.

```
os.chdir(str(home))
data9_2=pd.read_csv('edgarsdc3.csv')
os.chdir(str(home)+str('//defmtest'))

#import stuff
from nltk import pos_tag, ne_chunk
from nltk.tokenize import SpaceTokenizer

#define apply function and apply it
os.chdir(str(home)+str('//defmtest'))

####

#this is our apply function
def apply_extract_entities(row):
    names=[]
    counter=0
    print row
    for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(open(row['file_name'], "r+b").read()):
        for chunk in nltk.ne_chunk(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sent))):
            if hasattr(chunk, 'node'):
            names+= [chunk.node, ' '.join(c[0] for c in chunk.leaves())]
            counter+=1
            print counter
    return names


#need something that populates a list of sections of a dataframe
def dataframe_splitter(df):
     df_list=range(len(df))
     for i in xrange(len(df)):
         sliced=df.ix[i]
         df_list[i]=sliced
     return df_list

df_list=dataframe_splitter(data9_2)
#df_list=range(len(data9_2))
print df_list

#the multiprocessing section
import multiprocessing

def worker(arg):
    print arg
    (arg)['proper_nouns']=arg.apply(apply_extract_entities, axis=1)
    return arg

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=10)

# get list of pieces
res = pool.imap_unordered(worker, df_list[:5])
res2= list(itertools.chain(*res))
pool.close()
pool.join()

# re-assemble pieces into the final output
output = data9_2.head(1).concatenate(res)
print output.head()
```

Comment: see https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5751; this is partially implemented but actually is a bit non trivial when passing an arbitrary function because pickling the function is tricky; welcome for someone to have a look

Answer (score 2):

With multiprocessing, it's best to generate several large blocks of data, then re-assemble them to produce the final output.

### source

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(arg):
    return arg*2

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

# get list of pieces
res = pool.map(worker, [1,2,3])
pool.close()
pool.join()

# re-assemble pieces into the final output
output = sum(res)
print 'got:',output
```

### output

```
got: 12
```

Comment: That is a good idea. I was planning on doing something much more dynamic but much more complicated. I think your way is much better and simpler though. I will give it a try with the apply function and report back.

Comment: Instead of populating res, which waits for all of the workers to finish all available tasks, is there a way to get the output from worker 1 and append it into a dataframe, than say the output from worker 3 (order does not matter) and append that and so on?

Comment: yes: `Pool.imap_unordered()`, which is awesome, and does what you want: http://devdocs.io/python/library/multiprocessing#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap_unordered

Comment: I edited my question above to show what I have tried. It doesn't seem to work with imap or map..